# How do I use Images in pygame for collision detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

```
import pygame
import os

pygame.init()
# Images
bgImg = pygame.image.load("Images/background.png")
playerImgRight = (pygame.image.load("Images/playerRight.png"))
playerImgLeft = pygame.image.load("Images/playerLeft.png")
playerImgBack = pygame.image.load("Images/playerBack.png")
chestClosed = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("Images/chestsClosed.png"), (30, 40))
chestOpened = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("Images/chestOpen.png"), (30, 40))
currentPlayerImg = playerImgBack

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Richmonia")
pygame.display.set_icon(currentPlayerImg)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

playerX = 380
playerY = 380
playerXSpeed = 0
playerYSpeed = 0
```

Chest Class
I want but the collision detection in the chest update function

```
class Chest:
    def __init__(self, x, y, openImage, closeImage, playerX, playerY):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.openImage = openImage
        self.closeImage = closeImage
        self.currentImage = self.closeImage
        self.playerX = playerX
        self.playerY = playerY


    def update(self):
        print("Placeholder")

    def show(self):
        screen.blit(self.currentImage, (self.x, self.y))


chestOne = Chest(100, 100, chestOpened, chestClosed, playerX, playerY)

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                currentPlayerImg = playerImgBack
                playerYSpeed = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                currentPlayerImg = playerImgBack
                playerYSpeed = 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                currentPlayerImg = playerImgLeft
                playerXSpeed = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                currentPlayerImg = playerImgRight
                playerXSpeed = 5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerYSpeed = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerYSpeed = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerXSpeed = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerXSpeed = 0

    if playerY <= 0:
        playerY = 0
    if playerY >= 740:
        playerY = 740
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    if playerX >= 760:
        playerX = 760

    playerX += playerXSpeed
    playerY += playerYSpeed
    screen.blit(bgImg, (0, 0))
    chestOne.show()
    chestOne.update()

    screen.blit(currentPlayerImg, (playerX, playerY))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I know there is a way with sprites but I want to know if there is a way to do it with just the images.
Also bonus question how to I get the fps.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) object and [`colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to find a collision between a rectangle and an object.
[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position. The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument:

```py
running = True
while running:
    # [...]

    player_rect = currentPlayerImg.get_rect(topleft = (playerX, playerY))
    chestOne_rect = chestOne.currentImage.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y))
    if player_rect .colliderect(chestOne_rect):
        print("hit")

    # [...]
```

---

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time.
So in your case the frames per second are 60:

> ```py
> while running:
>    clock.tick(60)
> ```

[`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) returns the number of milliseconds passed since the previous call. If you call it in the application loop, then this is the number of milliseconds passed since the last frame.

```py
while run:
    ms_since_last_frame = clock.tick(60)
```